# strip unwanted html elements by retaining its content using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input with lots of html content. looking for a jquery function to efficiently strip the unwanted elements(just the elements, but would need to retain the content), the elements to retain would be the ones which i specify.
Also would like the function to be easily configurable to add or remove the elements i dont want. eg:
var tagsToRetain="p,i,u,br";

I have tried below, but that would require to specify the elements that i don't want, which would be tedious to do so.

```
$("span,h1,h2").each(function(){
$(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to specify which elements should *not* be processed by your `.each()` loop. If so, use the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) or the [`.not()` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$("body *:not(p,i,u,br)").each(function(){
   $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
});​

// OR:
$("body *").not("p,i,u,br").each(function(){
   $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
});​

// OR, encapsulated in a function with a clunky name:

function stripElementsNotSpecified(tagsToRetain) {
   $("body *").not(tagsToRetain).each(function(){
      $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
   });
}

stripElementsNotSpecified("p,i,u,br");​
```

Note that without the `"body *"` part of the selector the `:not(p,i,u.br)` part would select the html, head, script, etc., elements of your document. With `"body *"` it only selects children of the body.